# How to get the component's viewmodel from component's node in KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a component named 'my-component':

```
ko.components.register('my-component', { 

    viewModel: function() {      
        return { title: 'title' };     
    },

    template: '<div>x</div>'

});
```

I'm using this component in the view like that:

```
<my-component params=""></my-component>
```

Is there any way to get the component's view-model related to this HTML node? ko.dataFor doesn't work:

```
ko.dataFor($('my-component').get(0)) // it doesn't return component's view model
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm implementing a "reference" binding that will work similar to #references in Angular 2. For example if you want to set focus to some element using only code in HTML but without touching DOM or element's ID-s and without additional properties in the view-model. Getting view-model of the component will help me with communication also with components which have references.

Comment: You mean something like this? http://angular-tips.com/blog/2015/06/why-will-angular-2-rock/ (scroll down to middle of the page)

Comment: Exactly - in angular 2: <input type="text" #user/"> in knockout: <input type="text" data-bind="ref: user"/> and then <button data-bind="click: function() { $context.$$user.focus() }">

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
ko.dataFor($('my-component').get(0).firstChild);
```

Comment: It won't work synchronously during rendering the page, but it works when I call it after some time, like 10ms: setTimeout(function() { console.log(ko.dataFor(element.firstChild)), 10); So it's not an ideal solution. I think it's because the components are generated (filled) asynchronously.

Comment: But for now it's the best option. I will wait some time for some other ideas.

Comment: So to clarify, if we want to get component's view model using ko.dataFor function, we need to probe the HTML element that is inside this component instead of this component's HTML element itself.

Comment: Thanks cryss, that was not at all obvious, but was the only mention of this I have seen.

Comment: Documentation: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/unobtrusive-event-handling.html